# Why does JavaScript split() method return an array even if there is no separator?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a the grid of html elements, each with a `data-category` attribute on it.

Some `data-category` attributes have multiple values, separated by comma: `data-category="category 2, category 3"`.

Some have single values: `data-category="category 1"`, *without* a separator.

I use this simple script to filter the elements *by category*:

```js
$('#category-selector').on('change', function(){
  var $item = $('#items-container').find('.item'),
      current = $(this).val();
    if(current == 'all'){
       $item.fadeIn(200);
    } else {
       $item.hide(200);
       $item.each(function(){
          var category = $(this).data('category').split(', ');
          //console.log(category);
          if($.inArray(current, category) >= 0){
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
          }
       });
    }
});
```

```css
.posts-grid {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.posts-grid .block {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.posts-grid p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.posts-grid .block {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  margin-top: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="category-selector">
  <option value="all">Select Category</option>
  <option value="category 1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="category 2">Category 2</option>
  <option value="category 3">Category 3</option>
</select>

<div class="container" id="items-container">
  <div class="posts-grid row">
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1, category 2">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block">
          <p>1</p>
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 2, category 3">
      <div class="block">
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1, category 3">
      <div class="block">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block">
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 2">
      <div class="block">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1">
      <div class="block">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1">
      <div class="block">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1">
      <div class="block">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1">
      <div class="block">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1, category 2">
      <div class="block">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 2, category 3">
      <div class="block">
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-category="category 1">
      <div class="block">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was (pleasantly) surprised that my `split(', ')` method returns an array *even if there is no separator*.

**Questions:**

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is my filter reliable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Parameters

Comment: Because that's how it's [*defined to behave*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-string.prototype.split).

Comment: Check that the string contains the delimiter before spliiting. Or check the array size after splitting.

Comment: If the API behavior changed based on how many elements were returned you’d have to check the return type every time you used it. Split returns an array. Empty, one element, n elements. Reliable, predictable and consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `split` method is designed to work that way. From the documentation:

> When found, separator is removed from the string and the substrings are returned in an array. If separator is not found or is omitted, the array contains one element consisting of the entire string.

If you want a method that behaves differently, you can write a wrapper on top of split() that returns something else when the string doesn't have the delimiter (what would you rather it return?)

2. You filter still seems fine -- you are checking if the name of the category is in the array; if the array just consists of one element that corresponds to a category name, it'll be found; if the array consists of one element that is an empty string, it won't be found -- both are correct behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

It says:

> If separator is not found or is omitted, the array contains one element consisting of the entire string.

So, split will always return an array.
There is everything fine with your split() method